# App is crashing on NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter, ios12

While setting object to NSUserDefaults my App is crashing Randomly in iOS 12.Below is my code where the crash occurs

```
shared2 = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.AppName"];

NSData *datashare = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_sharedData];

[shared2 setObject:datashare forKey:@"dicForToday"];
```

Not getting any crash logs as it happens randomly

Frequency of this crash is much more on iOS 12.

Comment: What makes you think that's the code that's crashing? It looks like a networking error (see the references to `CFNetwork`).

Comment: @Stephen Darlington, I am sure that this crash is not related to the network issue,That log was for something else I also edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use this method for save data
Post Method:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:object forKey:@"somename"];
```

Get Method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicCover = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"somename"];
```

some time ,dictionary or array or not formatting right way we can use to achive your data like this to use `NSUserdefault`
Use Achive:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayUsers];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"somename"];
```

To get:

```
NSData *usersData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"somename"];
    NSMutableArray *redirectionDic = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:usersData];
```

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` From Apple's docs… _" this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_

Comment: …in iOS 12 and later, where it is a no-op. For backwards compatibility you will still need to call this in iOS 11 and below, so it doesn't hurt to keep it if you are targeting that's not the latest release.

Comment: @Developer1205, I am doing the same thing as you can see in the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
  NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                                  initWithSuiteName:keyChainGroup];
    [myDefaults setObject:userInfo forKey:key];
```

Try this

Comment: I am storing custom object in userDefaults by archiving custom class object into NSData. So, we do need that.

Comment: In my case i am storing JSON object inside my keychain group like this NSArray* userInfo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                                  initWithSuiteName:keyChainGroup];
    [myDefaults setObject:userInfo forKey:key];